# How can I make git-pull verbose by default?

Tags: git, github

Looking through the git-config variables and git-pull documentation I don't see a way to make git-pull pull verbose by default. Anybody know of a way?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's not a config parameter for everything! But you can mostly take care of it for yourself with an alias:

```
[alias]
    pv = pull -v
```

So you can use `git pv <args>`, save typing two characters, and get the verbosity you want.

Comment: Isn't it **FIVE** characters you are saving?

Comment: This alias is to added in git config file, preferntially the global for all repos, this can be done using :

`git config --global --add alias.pv "pull -v"`

Comment: @FelipeAlvarez 6 if you count the space :)

Answer (score 1):

In your git global config file, you can create "aliases".

It is usefull to create new git commands (ignore, for example), or to define a default comportement to an existing command (in your case).