# Using git remote --verbose by default

Tags: git

I'm trying a way to make the command `git remote` to use the `--verbose` option by default on all my repositories.

Inspired by a working solution to add option `--rebase` to `git pull`, I have tried the command `git config --global remote.verbose true`, which produces no errors but is not working.

I have seen [a 2012 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696025/how-can-i-make-git-pull-verbose-by-default) proposing to use an alias, but I don't like that solution. I would like to know if modern git (I have version 2.17.1) has added some option since 2012.

So any idea to make `git remote` work like `git remote --verbose`?

Comment: Not sure there's such think as a `loud-remote` mode like with `rebase`.  
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-remotepushDefault

Comment: No. Alias is the only solution.

Comment: I used a [git alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases): `git config --global alias.re 'remote -v'`, then `git re` does what you want.